# SignalR Hub Acts as TCP Client

Tags: wcf, sockets, signalr, tcpclient, tcpserver

Here is my situation:

I have a windows service that constantly runs and receives data from connected hardware on TCP/IP port. This data needs to be pushed to Asp.net website for real-time display as well as stored in database. The windows service, asp.net website and database are all located on the same server.

For Widnows Service: I can't use WCF because it only supports netTCP which is not going to work with socket communication over TCP. So I have to use TCP socket communication for TCP Server/Client.

For Real-Time Updates to the website: I am planning to use SignalR library. I can create a hub which should send new data to clients whevener it becomes available.

My problem is: What's the best way for signalR hub to retrieve data from TCP Server/Client located in Windows service? One simple solution is to first store data in database and retrieve from there. But I am not sure if that is going to slow down the whole system as data received is going to be every second.

Please advise a best solution for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You could run a .NET SignalR client connected to localhost inside your Windows service to communicate with the SignalR Hub if you don't want to poll the database.

Comment: Hi Halter. Thanks for your response. That's what I am trying to see how to use signalr to receive data from tcp server?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client

Comment: What method used for the above to solve? Please let me know if find a solution..